# Creating POD with variable number of elems

Tags: templates, c++11, variadic

I would like to have a type, that would be in effect POD but I would like to be able to specify how and which types are in it, for example:

```
template<Args...>
struct POD
{
//here I would like to create depending on Args appropriate types as a members.
};
```

Is it possible to do it with this new variadic templates feature in C++0x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’ve never yet used the C++0x variadic templates feature but the following code compiles on G++ 4.5:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct tuple;

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct tuple<T, Args...> {
    T value;
    tuple<Args...> inner;
};

template <typename T>
struct tuple<T> {
    T value;
};
```

However, initializing them is … weird because we need to *nest* the inner values:

```
int main() {
    tuple<int> n1 = { 23 };
    tuple<int, float> n2 = { 42, { 0.5f } };
    tuple<std::string, double, int> n3 = { "hello, world", { 3.14, { 97 } } };
}
```

Retrieving the values is of course a bit tedious. The simplest method is probably to provide a `get<N>()` function template.

But we cannot implement `get` directly since function templates cannot be partially specialized. Either we need to use SFINAE (read: `boost::enable_if`) or we need to delegate the actual function of `get` to a type that can be partially specialized.

In the following, I did the latter. But first, we need another helper type trait: `nth_type`, which returns the appropriate return type of the `get` function:

```
template <unsigned N, typename... Args>
struct nth_type;

template <unsigned N, typename T, typename... Args>
struct nth_type<N, T, Args...> : nth_type<N - 1, Args...> { };

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct nth_type<0, T, Args...> {
    typedef T type;
};
```

Easy-peasy. Just returns the *n*th type in a list of types.

Now we can write our `get` function:

```
template <unsigned N, typename... Args>
inline typename nth_type<N, Args...>::type get(tuple<Args...>& tup) {
    return get_t<N, Args...>::value(tup);
}
```

Like I said, this just delegates the task. No biggie. In practice, we probably want to have another overload for `const` tuples (but then, in practice we would use an existing `tuple` type).

Now for the killing, followed by a light salad:

```
template <unsigned N, typename... Args>
struct get_t;

template <unsigned N, typename T, typename... Args>
struct get_t<N, T, Args...> {
    static typename nth_type<N, T, Args...>::type value(tuple<T, Args...>& tup) {
        return get_t<N - 1, Args...>::value(tup.inner);
    }
};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
struct get_t<0, T, Args...> {
    static T value(tuple<T, Args...>& tup) {
        return tup.value;
    }
};
```

And that’s it. We can test this by printing some values in our previously defined variables:

```
std::cout << get<0>(n1) << std::endl; // 23
std::cout << get<0>(n2) << std::endl; // 42
std::cout << get<0>(n3) << std::endl; // hello, world

std::cout << get<1>(n2) << std::endl; // 0.5
std::cout << get<1>(n3) << std::endl; // 3.14

std::cout << get<2>(n3) << std::endl; // 97
```

Man, it’s *fun* messing with variadic templates.

Comment: I was so sure that the composed member would *necessarily* be non-POD, thus making the type itself non-POD, that I had completely ruled out this solution :)

Comment: There'a a std::tuple that also provides get<N>, I believe.

Comment: @DeadMG: of course. This is just to show how it would be done, not to create production code. That said, is `std::tuple` a POD?

Comment: **Nota bene:** Of course, the above `tuple` class is only a POD if every of its template arguments is a POD. The third example uses `std::string` and consequently isn’t a POD.

Comment: If all it's arguments are PODs, then yes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with [`std::tuple`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982837.aspx)?

AFAIK it's a POD if all it's members are PODs, if I'm wrong then I'm guessing it isn't possible.